# EKS Cluster Scale off Network Bandwidth

Tags: devops, amazon-eks

We're hosting a web application in an AWS EKS cluster that is mainly just serving up content or accepting imagines/inputs from the user. We found through stress testing that our existing infrastructure on 2 T3.medium nodes was only able to handle a very small number of concurrent users due to maxing out on the network bandwidth. cpu and memory were extremely low during the tests. After manually updating to 6 nodes and T3.2xlarge instance types we saw a 10x increase in connections per second in our testing. We want to be able to autoscale the number of nodes to allow our environment to scale somewhat whereas the instance types I imagine would have to be a manual tweak once nodes start to get high. We currently have an autoscaler setup through a helm-chart but is not utilizing network load as I believe that's not natively supported by EKS.

I was wondering if stackoverflow would point me in the right direction in setting up a way to capture the network metrics on the nodes in the cluster or just some way of tracking overall network traffic and if it reaches certain thresholds it increase or decreases the nodes that would be great.

Just a quick note I have little to no devops knowledge/experience. Our devops guy left and I've just been trying to hold down the ship ever since.

I've used chatgpt to try and setup a metrics-server but inevitably ran into issues and I'm not confident it's even up to date and question whether it knows what it's talking about.

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't use t (burstable) family instances for running containers. Performance can be unpredictable. You could try monitoring raw network throughput, but oftentimes request rate, i.e. requests per second, is a better metric (and easier to measure). You can use keda.sh to scale your deployments according to an external metric like request rate, see https://dev.to/k6/how-to-autoscale-kubernetes-pods-with-keda-testing-with-k6-4nl9 for an example. If you're nodes are becoming saturated, consider reducing the number of pods per node (reducing max-pods) or using an instance type with greater bandwidth, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-network-bandwidth.html. Good luck!